# Android: random images changed when device is rotated to landscape mode

Tags: android

I build an app which shows 3 random images from an SQLite database. But when I rotate my device to landscape mode, the random images are changed.

I don't want that actually, what I want is the 3 random images stay still either on portrait or landscape mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below property in your manifest in that particular `Activity` node.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this happening is that the Activity is re-created when rotating to landscape mode. There are various ways around this:

1. Move initialization out of Activity onCreate : [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)
2. Move the logic to a separate class (which does the random picking) and get the data from this class (well, a Model class, to be more specific).