# Android saving text in TextView after orientation change

Tags: android, textview

I've tried 100 things to solve this, but none of them seem to work for saving text in a TextView when my orientation changes.

On orientation change, none of these functions are ever called:

```
onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), 
onRestoreInstanceState(),
onSaveInstanceState()
```

Note that I have `android:configChanges="orientation"` in my manifest for this activity so `onConfigurationChanged()` is called instead of `onCreate()` since I want `onCreate()` to only run once.

Anyone have any ideas at all to fix this?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370943/android-random-images-changed-when-device-is-rotated-to-landscape-mode/6371138#6371138

Comment: on orientation change android will called onResume()/onStart() method if that is present in your code.

Comment: none of these are really answering how i can save the text in a textview when the orientation changes...

Comment: Yes it does, you save the text in onPause/onStop and read it back in in onResume/onStart

Comment: onPause is not called on orientation change

Answer (score 1):

If you specify android:configChanges then all of this methods will not be called. See [Activity ConfigurationChanges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) and [Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29). Only [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method will be called.

Comment: that's pretty much what i said in my primary post, but how can I save the info in the textview so that I can re-insert it after the orientation changes?

Comment: I just wanted to explain that these methods should not be called... TextView shouldn't be automatically cleared on configuration change. What do you have in `onConfigurationChanged()` method?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main) and the findViewById(...) calls to get the objects by id.

Comment: Save content of TextView before call to setContentView and restore content after findViewById. Also, it is not needed to set the content view in most cases.

Comment: i removed setContentView and the text remained. thanks. Im not even sure why I put hat there.